# New data frame with the % of the debt paid in the month of the payment

Tags: python, python-3.x, pandas, dataframe

I have two dataframes `df1` and `df2`.
One with clients `debt`, the other with client `payments` with `dates`.

I want to create a new data frame with the % of the debt paid in the month of the payment until `01-2017`.

```
import pandas as pd

d1 = {'client number': ['2', '2','3','6','7','7','8','8','8','8','8','8','8','8'],
     'month': [1, 2, 3,1,10,12,3,5,8,1,2,4,5,8],
    'year':[2013,2013,2013,2019,2013,2013,2013,2013,2013,2014,2014,2015,2016,2017],
    'payment' :[100,100,200,10000,200,100,300,500,200,100,200,200,500,50]}

df1 = pd.DataFrame(data=d1).set_index('client number')
df1
d2 = {'client number': ['2','3','6','7','8'],
     'debt': [200, 600,10000,300,3000]}

df2 = pd.DataFrame(data=d2)


x=[1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10]
y=[2013,2014,2015,2016,2017]

for x in month and y in year
if df1['month']=x and df1['year']=year :
    df2[month&year] = df1['payment']/df2['debt']
```

the result needs to be something like this for all the clients

[image]

what am I missing?

thank you for your time and help

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First set the `index` of both the dataframes `df1` and `df2` to `client number`, then use [`Index.map`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.Index.map.html) to map the client numbers in `df1` to their corresponding `debt's` from `df2`, then use [`Series.div`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.Series.div.html) to divide the `payments` of each client by their respective `debt's`, thus obtaining the fraction of debt which is paid, then create a new column `date` in `df1` from `month` and `year` columns finally use [`DataFrame.join`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.join.html) along with [`DataFrame.pivot_table`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.pivot_table.html):

```
df1 = df1.set_index('client number')
df2 = df2.set_index('client number')

df1['pct'] = df1['payment'].div(df1.index.map(df2['debt'])).round(2)
df1['date'] = df1['year'].astype(str) + '-' + df1['month'].astype(str).str.zfill(2)

df3 = (
    df2.join(
        df1.pivot_table(index=df1.index, columns='date', values='pct', aggfunc='sum').fillna(0))
    .reset_index()
)
```

Result:

```
# print(df3)

  client number   debt  2013-01  2013-02  2013-03  2013-05  2013-08  ...  2013-12  2014-01  2014-02  2015-04  2016-05  2017-08  2019-01
0             2    200      0.5      0.5     0.00     0.00     0.00  ...     0.00     0.00     0.00     0.00     0.00     0.00      0.0
1             3    600      0.0      0.0     0.33     0.00     0.00  ...     0.00     0.00     0.00     0.00     0.00     0.00      0.0
2             6  10000      0.0      0.0     0.00     0.00     0.00  ...     0.00     0.00     0.00     0.00     0.00     0.00      1.0
3             7    300      0.0      0.0     0.00     0.00     0.00  ...     0.33     0.00     0.00     0.00     0.00     0.00      0.0
4             8   3000      0.0      0.0     0.10     0.17     0.07  ...     0.00     0.03     0.07     0.07     0.17     0.02      0.0
```

Comment: Hi there! Thanks for the help! When i apply that script to my values , it shows Error : Index contains duplicate entries, cannot reshape

Comment: Does your `df2` dataframe contains `duplicated` values for client number?

Comment: there are a few clients that could pay twice in a month... is that the issue ?

Comment: df2 dont have duplicate values

Comment: @Yep that's a issue..give me some time, so that i could possibly think of an alternate solution.

Comment: thank you very much, i can tip you in ethereum for this

Comment: That's really not required ;).

Comment: @TiagoEmanuelPratas edited the answer..i guess this should work now.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/216734/discussion-between-tiago-emanuel-pratas-and-shubham-sharma).

Comment: glad you enjoyed! i will publish more no worries ahaha